# Determining presence of prototype with correct return type

Tags: c, prototype

Here's a random problem in C black magic I just came up with:

Write a function that returns 1 if `malloc` has been prototyped to return a pointer type and 0 if `malloc` has a return type of `int` (either implicitly or due to wrong prototype), *without invoking any implementation-defined or undefined behavior*.

I believe it's solvable, but I haven't worked out the solution. Note that calling the function cannot be necessary and in fact is not possible since calling a function with the incorrect prototype is undefined behavior. I have some ideas for ingredients but I think it makes for a better puzzle (and possibly more diverse ideas) if I leave them out for now.

I don't need the solution for any immediate use, but it could be handy in `configure` scripts and such.

**Update:** A better example of the usefulness (with `strdup` instead of `malloc`):

```
#undef strdup
#define strdup(x) (strdup_has_proto ? strdup((x)) : my_strdup((x)))
```

i.e. being able to implement `X_has_proto` as an expression at the source level could be a portable way to use functions which a system might or might not have, and fall back on a local replacement, without needing any separate `configure` step.

Comment: @R.. So it's a function *outside* of C that's to determine the prototyping?

Comment: I mean internally in the same translation unit context, not from the outside by running the preprocessor and parsing or looking for compiler warnings.

Comment: If you're on a system where an int and a pointer are different sizes, you could compare the sizeof() the return value of malloc with that of int and void*, but that's as far as I've got so far.

Comment: Yeah, sadly that fails on 32-bit machines, but perhaps it's still useful since on most 32-bit implementations, the missing prototype will not actually affect code generation. The method I'm looking at involves `?:` magic but I'm beginning to doubt whether it can be made to work.

Comment: @R. the implicit function declaration part is easy :) C99 removes this feature from the language. So using any symbol in a context that implies that this is a function symbol is undefined behavior, I think.

Comment: @Jens: Hmm, that may be the answer...

Comment: @Jens: On the other hand, if my goal is just to use this in place of `configure` checks on a program which is intended to run on a fully POSIX-conformant environment, but which also supports legacy systems which are semi-POSIX but missing certain interfaces, I think it's arguably very reasonable to assume that undeclared functions implicitly have a return type of `int`. Of course a POSIX-conforming system also conforms to C99, but it doesn't have missing prototypes, so the UB never gets invoked.

Comment: @R: Well the problem is even deeper than that. Since it is undefined behavior, a compiler may do what pleases, and seemingly they do. E.g for gcc the program `int main(void) { return toto(0); }` behaves differently if you replace `toto` by the word `malloc`. With `toto` it assumes `int` and everything is ok, for `malloc` it assumes `void*` even though there is no prototype. So you wouldn't detect anything, with a macro or other tricks, unless you really'd have the *wrong* prototype for `malloc` somewhere.

Comment: I guess my idea of the usefulness of this question evolved a bit since I asked it. I was originally thinking along the lines of detecting foolish mistakes like forgetting a header file (thus the `malloc` example) without needing the compiler's warnings, but I later realized it's probably more useful for finding functions with (potentially-)missing implementations on legacy systems, and reimplementing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some partial answers and answers to related questions:

If the function in question is supposed to return a floating point type, the test is easy:

```
#define HAS_PROTO_FP_RET_1_ARG(f) !!((1?1:(f)(0))/2)
```

The 1 gets promoted to a floating point type if and only if `f` is declared to return a floating point type, and division by 2 results in a nonzero value if and only if 1 has floating point type.

This test could be useful for checking for the presence of C99 math functions.

With pointers, the expression `(1?0:(f)(0))` is potentially useful - it evaluates to either `0` (an `int`) or `(void *)0)` (a null pointer constant) depending on the return type of `f`. But I have yet to find any devious way to test whether an expression has integer or pointer type.

The big problem I'm running into is that `void *` cannot participate in pointer arithmetic and does not implicitly convert to other pointer types in arithmetic contexts. For example, if it did, this would work (slightly breaking my rules about UB/IDB too):

```
#define HAS_PROTO_PTR_RET_1_ARG(f) ((int)((char (*)[2])2 - (1?0:(f)(0))) == 1)
```

Any ideas for getting around this problem?

**Update:** I have a solution that depends on nothing more than `intmax_t` being larger than `int`:

```
#define HAS_PROTO_PTR_RET_1_ARG(f) ( \
    sizeof(int)!=sizeof(void *) ? sizeof ((f)(0)) == sizeof(void *) : \
    sizeof (1?(intmax_t)0:(f)(0)) == sizeof(void *) )
```

There are two cases. If `int` and `void *` have different sizes, we simply check the size of the return value. Otherwise, `int` and `void *` are the same size, so (by the big assumption) `intmax_t` and `void *` are not the same size. We construct an expression whose type is `intmax_t` if the return type is `int`, and `void *` if the return type is `void *`, and test its size.

This macro fails only on machines where `int`, `intmax_t`, and `void *` all have the same size. Practically speaking, that means only on DSPs with 64-bit or larger `int`. Since pretty much all real POSIX and POSIX-like systems have fixed-size 32-bit int and `intmax_t` is required to be at least 64-bit, this is portable enough to make me happy.

Comment: nope, for any pointer to a type with `sizeof > 1` this could be done. But `char*` (and derivates) is not distinguishable from integers and `void*` can't do arithmetic. But your trick for float is cute.

Comment: @Jens: I've gotten pretty close to making a universal solution. Close enough for my needs anyway.

Comment: Nice. Indeed a quite reasonable assumption. The other implicit assumption that you carry along is that pointer types all have the same width as `void*`. So your solution is a valid test for `void*`. Maybe on weird archs there are data pointers that are narrower. And then, you don't capture function pointers. They are not even conversion compatible with `void*`. But yeah, you solved the "missing prototype for `malloc` problem". Great!

Comment: @Jens: Indeed all pointer types can be different, but if you know the correct type you expect, you can just replace `void *` with that type and it works. And of course for anything but `char` types and `void`, the other trick usually works anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution given the assumptions.  What you need is a function whose body has free variables that represent the intermediate type information in the compiler that isn't ever lowered into the target language except in implementation-defined ways, e.g. debugger information.  Relax the requirements so that you allow certain prescribed kinds of implementation-defined behavior, and you might find a solution.

Comment: `(1?0:malloc(1))` is an expression that evaluates to `0` (`(int)0`) if `malloc` has return type `int` and to a null pointer constant if `malloc` has return type `void *`, but I haven't yet found any way to detect whether the type of an expression is an integer or a pointer...

Comment: You can't detect at runtime without using an implementation-dependent method, e.g. invoking the compiler with `system()` on a source text that attempts to evaluate the constant expression `sizeof strdup(1)[0]`, which sadly won't work with any function that returns `void*`.  See what I mean?  No solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since `void *` and `int` can be added I was thinking of other operators to try, such as comparison.  The results, especially with R's `?:` trick are oddly inconsistent:

```
int f() { return 0; }

void *g() { return 0; }

#define T(x)  (1?0:x())   /* R's trick from a comment */

void h()
{
    void *n = 0;
    int i = 0;

    f() > n;  /* m.c:12: warning: comparison between pointer and integer */
    g() > n;
    T(f) > n;
    T(g) > n;

    f() > i;
    g() > i;  /* m.c:18: warning: comparison between pointer and integer */
    T(f) > i;
    T(g) > i; /* m.c:20: warning: comparison between pointer and integer */
}
```

Answer (score -2):

How about some gloriously bad hacks?

```
char has_malloc = 0;
#define malloc(x) \
     has_malloc = 1; \
     malloc((x))
//.. run includes here
#undef malloc
```

But then, you could just `#include <malloc.h>` for the guarantee.

Edit:
Why not just define an int malloc()? If anyone tries to call an int malloc, it should call your version instead.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with my question and is full of incorrect information. `#include <malloc.h>` is a nonstandard header, defining `int malloc()` with external linkage results in undefined behavior, and nowhere did I indicate any desire to do such a think in this question.